# PDFBox leaves font files open after generating PDF

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I am experiencing problems with TTF fonts loaded for generating PDFs which eventually result in too many open files on Linux. The PDFBox version I tested last was 2.0.0-RC3.

Basically for each PDF I create a document and load two fonts which I want to use. After the document is generated I close all the resources, but the file descriptors for both fonts remain open.

My question is how do I close these two files?

This is my basic code:

```
doc = new PDDocument();
page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
doc.addPage(page);

PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File(settings.getProperty("font.location")));
PDFont boldFont = PDType0Font.load(doc, new File(settings.getProperty("bold.font.location")));

PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
// add content stuff

content.close();
bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(bos);
bos.flush();
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
doc.close();
```

Comment: Do you ever close your PDDocument object?

Comment: Lets say that the answer to my previous question is yes - in that case, please open an issue in JIRA, and include some code with a standard font, and a loop, and mention how long the loop should be to have the effect you mention. Do also mention what JDK you are using and what Linux flavour.

Comment: @Tilman, I do, I just didn't paste all the code in the example. I edited the example code now to also include the doc close statement.

Comment: Try this workaround: TrueTypeFont ttf = new TTFParser().parse(new File(....)); PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, ttf, true); (....)  ttf.close();

Comment: This bug - which occured when fonts were opened but not used - was fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4242 , it will be in the 2.0.12 release.